# How to check a special form of Companion Matrix is a Primitive Matrix or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, companion-matrices

**Definition:** A non-negative matrix square $A$ is called *primitive* if there is a $k$ such that all the entries of $A^k$ are positive.[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem)

**Lemma:** If the graph associated to $A$ is strongly connected and has two cycles of relatively prime lengths, then $A$ is primitive.[[2]](http://www.math.harvard.edu/library/sternberg/slides/1180912pf.pdf)

**Corollary 8.5.8 (Wielandt):** Let $A\in M_n$ be non-negative. Then $A$ is primitive if and only if $A^{n^2-2n+2}>0$.[[3]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521548233)

Now consider the following form of the  [Companion  Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) 
$$
C_n=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
0 &1 &0 &\cdots &\cdots &0 \\
0 &0 &1 &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots \\
\vdots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots \\
\vdots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &0 \\
0 &\cdots &\cdots &0&0 &1 \\
1 &u_1 &u_2 &\cdots &u_{n-2} &u_{n-1}
\end{array}
\right)_{n\times n}
$$
where $u_i\in \{0,1\}$, for $1\leq i \leq n-1$. Based on the Corollary 8.5.8, for every selection of $u_i$'s, we compute $C_n^{n^2-2n+2}$ and if all entries of $C_n^{n^2-2n+2}$, denoted by $C_n^{n^2-2n+2}[i,j]$, $1\leq i,j\leq n$, be positive integer numbers then we conclude that $C_n$ is a primitive matrix, otherwise it results that $C_n$ is not a  primitive matrix.

*Example:* For $n=6$, assume that $V=(u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,u_5)$ then, 
with selections $V=(1,0,0,0,0)$ and $V=(0,0,0,0,1)$, the $C_6$ is a primitive matrix and by choosing $V=(0,1,0,0,0)$, $V=(0,0,1,0,0)$ and $V=(0,0,0,1,0)$, the $C_6$ is not a primitive matrix.

*My question:* Is there other methods to verify that with selection $u_i$'s the $C_n$ is a  primitive matrix or not? For example, suppose that $n=2m$ and $V=(u_1,\cdots,u_{2m-1})=(0,1,0,1,0,\cdots,1,0)$ then how to prove that $C_n$ is not a primitive matrix?

I know that the characteristic polynomial of $C_n$ is $char(C_n)=x^n-u_{n-1}x^{n-1}-\cdots -u_1x-1$, but how to use $char(C_n)$ to answer question.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: the second is not a definition, but a lemma

Comment: @Exodd Thanks, the question is edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second definition is actually a lemma, and it is quite powerful:

> Given a graph, then the associated matrix $A$ is primitive if and only if the graph is strongly connected and has two cycles of relatively prime lengths.

If you draw the graph associated to $A$, you can notice that if $u_{i_1},u_{i_2},\dots,u_{i_s}$ are the only 1 entries, then the graph has only the simple cycles of length  $n,n-i_1,n-i_2,\dots,n-i_s$.

Using the above result, you get that $A$ is primitive if and only if
$$
gcd(n,n-i_1,n-i_2,\dots,n-i_s)=1
$$

Comment: Thank you for your interesting answer. I want to ask a question. By your answer, if $n=2$ and $u_1=1$ then $C_2$ is a primitive matrix since $C_n$ has simple cycles of length of $2$ and $1$. My question is that when I draw the graph of $C_2$, we have two simple cycles of length $2$? What is wrong about my discussion. Is it possible to ask you to explain more your statement "the graph has only the simple cycles of length  $n,n-i_1,n-i_2,\dots,n-i_s$". Thanks again.

Comment: in $C_2$ there's a loop on the last node, that is considered a cycle of lenght 1

Comment: There is a nice relation between root of $char(C_n)$ and $\gcd$ of $u_i$'s,  maybe you find it interesting. If $u_{i_1},u_{i_2},\dots,u_{i_s}$ be the only non-zero of $u_i$'s then $char(C_n)$ has one large positive real eigenvalue(satisfies the [Perron property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem)) if and only if $gcd(n,n-i_1,n-i_2,\dots,n-i_s)=1$.

Comment: @Amin235 Isn't that a general property of Markov chains and primitive matrix?

Comment: I have a question. The lemma that I mentioned in the question is necessary and not sufficient but in the answer you used it in necessary and sufficient cases. I mean,  what is reference of this one "If $A$ be a primitive matrix then the graph of  $A$ is strongly connected and has two cycles of relatively prime lengths". Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Amin235 http://www.math.harvard.edu/library/sternberg/slides/1180912pf.pdf 
Slide 28

Comment: In slide 28 is written "If the graph associated to M is strongly connected and has two
cycles of relatively prime lengths, then M is primitive" Not if and only if. I think the lemma in answer is true because of Theorem 8.5.3. of [this book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0521548233/?tag=stackoverfl08-20)

Comment: @Amin235 in slide 28, right above the theorem you cited, there's the proof of the converse, since it is way easier

Comment: Is the theorem that is mentioned in the answer, true over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ where $q$ is a prime power? Thanks.

Comment: @Amin235 Try asking an other question

Comment: You right but I found a counterexample that is: consider the circulant matrix $C=cir(0,1,1,0)$. Although $C$ is a primitive matrix over $\mathbb{R}$,  it can checked that the $4$th power of $C$ is zero matrix over $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ for some $n$. Am I right?

Comment: @Amin235 how is that a counterexample? $C^3$ is always full in every $\mathbb F_{2^n}$ so it is primitive even in those finite fields

Comment: I know that but consider a non-negative matrix $A$. We know that if $A^m$ be a positive matrix then $A^n$ for $n\geq m$ is a positive matrix but in  $\mathbb F_{2^n}$ is not true. Because of thus I made this example.

Comment: And that is why I suggested you ask a new question separated from this chat/thread. I'm actually at lesson